# How to extract a certain bandwidth of frequency from image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to remove frequency components that are not in this band, 760nm-900nm peak wavelength centered at 850nm in opencv but I cannot understand how to remove it through python/opencv. I understand how DFT could be applied but I cannot get how the frequency could be removed from the image with these exact values of wavelength. (f=c/wavelength)

Comment: Can you please add some pictures. It will help us understand the question better.

Comment: Maybe you could put an IR filter over your lens?